# Post data to RESTful by backbone

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

First time of trying to post data from backbone to REST using model collection of backbone.

```
define(["underscore" , "backbone"],function(_ , Backbone){
  var CustomerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'http://myresturl/api/CusWeb',
    initialize: function(){

    },
    defaults : {
        UID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        Sex: 0,
        Name: "",
        Company: "",
        Address: "",
        Email: ""
    }
  });
  return CustomerModel;
});

define(["underscore","backbone","models/CustomerModel"] , function(_ ,Backbone,CustomerModel){
  var CustomerCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://myresturl/api/CusWeb',
    model:CustomerModel
  });
  return CustomerCollection;
});
```

I'm trying to post data from backbone to REST URL by clicking on a button in backbone view.

```
define(["jquery" ,
  "underscore" ,
  "backbone" ,
  "text!templates/Customer/registerCustomerTemplate.html",
  "models/CustomerModel",
  "user",
],function($ , _ , Backbone, RegisterDescriptionTem, CustomerModel, Customer){
   var userObj = new Customer();

   var ContainerRegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $("#webbodycontainer"),
    initialize : function(){

    },
    events : {
        'click #register' : 'registerUser'
    },
    registerUser : function(){
        this.model.set({
            UID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            Sex: 1,
            Name: "",
            Company: "",
            Address: "",
            Email: ""
        });
        this.model.save();
        console.log(this.model.get('Sex'));
    },
    render : function(){
        var _registerDes = _.template(RegisterDescriptionTem);
        this.model = new CustomerModel();
        this.$el.append(_registerDes((this.model.toJSON())));
    }
  });
  return ContainerRegisterView;
});
```

`console.log(this.model.get('Sex'));` is shown in browser's console (1) but data didn't save to database.

Here is the router :

```
 define([
    .....
      'views/Customer/ContainerRegister',
 ], function(ContainerRegister){
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
       routes: {
      ......

       }

   var app_router = new AppRouter;
   app_router.on('route:registerAction', function(register){
       if(window.currentSection){
          window.currentSection.remove();
       }
       window.currentSection = new ContainerRegister({});
       $('#webbodycontainer').html(window.currentSection.$el);
       window.currentSection.render(register);
     });
 });
```

I appreciate any other information that you can provide. Thanks.

Comment: When you save model, do you see request to server on network's page of developer tools?

Comment: @Sergey :  No, I don't.

Comment: Well, if you not have request to REST, then you have error in a Backbone App. Try to set `debugger;` before `this.model.save();` and debug

Comment: @Sergey : Do I have to set up `backbone debugger` extension to debug or backbone has its own debugger? I didn't found it by searching Google.

Comment: debugger means you have to debug the .js file through browser dude. use firebug for better view. Go to scripts and set debug points

Comment: What happens if you manually try to submit a POST request to the URL (urlRoot: 'http://myresturl/api/CusWeb')?

Comment: @MarcB. :Manually posting is working fine.

Comment: Not sure if this relates to the problem or not, but `render()` needs to return `this` in your View.

Comment: @J.Titus : Thanks J. TItus, but nothing has changed after add `return this;` :)

Answer (score 3):

Check initializing your model. and also while saving try to give first parameter as null.

```
define(["jquery" ,
    "underscore" ,
    "backbone" ,
    "text!templates/Customer/registerCustomerTemplate.html",
    "models/CustomerModel",
    "user",
  ],function($ , _ , Backbone, RegisterDescriptionTem, CustomerModel, Customer){

     var ContainerRegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el : $("#webbodycontainer"),
      //check initializing your model here.
      initialize : function(){
          _.bindAll(this);
          this.model = new Customer();
      },
      events : {
          'click #register' : 'registerUser'
      },
      registerUser : function(){
          this.model.set({
              UID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              Sex: 1,
              Name: "",
              Company: "",
              Address: "",
              Email: ""
          });
          this.model.save(null,{
            success:function(){
                //code after success
            },error:function(){
                //code after error
            },
          });
          console.log(this.model.get('Sex'));
      },
      render : function(){
          var _registerDes = _.template(RegisterDescriptionTem);
          this.model = new CustomerModel();
          this.$el.append(_registerDes((this.model.toJSON())));
      }
    });
    return ContainerRegisterView;
  });
```

Comment: Hey Nakul91, I got this error `Uncaught Error: bindAll must be passed function names `.

Comment: remove that line and check once.

Comment: Removed that line, and there's nothing change (this.model.save() didn't work).

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be lack of a model `id`. For backbone<->server interactions, you might find that the `id` property is required. Try modifying your code as follows:

```
define(["underscore" , "backbone"],function(_ , Backbone){
  var CustomerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'http://myresturl/api/CusWeb',
    initialize: function(){

    },
    defaults : {
        UID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        Sex: 0,
        Name: "",
        Company: "",
        Address: "",
        Email: ""
    },
    idAttribute: "UID" // set "UID" as the alias for "id"
  });
  return CustomerModel;
});
```

Here's a blog post on a similar issue that goes into a little more detail http://blog.markstarkman.com/blog/2012/02/13/getting-backbone-dot-js-to-sync-with-rails-and-mongoid/

Comment: It didn't appear any change when putting `idAttribute`. One more thing that I curious, `this.model.save` seems not working, `success` and `error` function didn't display any message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to set idAttribute on model as @SteamDev said.

```
var CustomerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'http://myresturl/api/CusWeb',
    initialize: function(){

    },
    defaults : {
        //UID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        Sex: 0,
        Name: "",
        Company: "",
        Address: "",
        Email: ""
    },
    idAttribute: "UID" // set "UID" as the alias for "id"
  });
```

Secondly, you don't need to set UID value (neither on defaults of model, nor on model instance).

Comment: Still have nothing changed after modifying.

Comment: Can you show me how are you passing model to `ContainerRegisterView` when you do `new ContainerRegisterView()`?

Comment: I added the router's block where I did `new` of my view, and passing model to view, I was doing it in the `render()` method in my view.